# What kind of telecommunication systems do astronauts use in space?

Tags: space-mission

What kind of telecommunication systems do the astronauts use in space? I ask about both earth-to-space and space-to-space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It varies on every mission, but on the Space Shuttle, NASA has compiled [an impressive list](http://www.spaceflight.nasa.gov/shuttle/reference/shutref/orbiter/comm/) of the different communication technologies they use for different purposes.

Pretty much all of these are various variations on radio or microwave communications (the [S-band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_band) and [Ku-band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ku_band)). [UH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra_high_frequency)F is used as a backup, especially for EVAs.